# Live Streaming Video Camera?

Tags: streaming, youtube, camcorder, rtmp

Are there any video cameras (recording over 30 minutes of footage length) that have live streaming services (RTMP) built-in to the camera? I know there are a ton of cameras with YouTube (etc.) uploading capabilities with built-in Wi-Fi, but I'm asking specifically for live streaming.

Answer (score 1):

The JVC  GY-HM200 has live streaming capabilities - http://pro.jvc.com/prof/attributes/features.jsp?model_id=MDL102319.

I've never used that particular model (so have no personal experience of the live streaming functions) but I do use the 170 and it's a solid little camcorder with a great range of options (including shooting in 4K and at high speed - though not at the same time), it's fairly robust and delivers great quality for the price.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're attempting to be out and about and live streaming from a hotspot, look into just outputting the camera directly to a computer (or a switchboard if you need it), and capturing that footage with something like OBS.

Provided you're on a budget, you can probably just connect whatever camera to your existing laptop with the right cords and use OBS to connect to the RTMP, and that works for both options.

Another option is to use a gopro, so the camera can be wirelessly connected to the hotspot, the footage can be displayed and window/monitor captured from the computer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't answer the question. I'm fully capable of setting up a computer to publish a live feed. I'm looking for video recording and publishing in one unit.

Comment: It wouldn't let me comment to clarify on your post so I laid some options for you, or more likely, other people that stumbled onto this looking for streaming on the go options.  Best of luck.